# Jquery Slider with checkboxes menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a Jquery slider to switch between several checkboxes menus.

The image below shows the behavior I want to implement:

[image]

Here is what I have tried so far: https://jsfiddle.net/x5otevf0/1/

**HTML:**

```html
<!-- 
 * Jquery Image Slider Tutorial 
 * File : index.html
 * Author : Krishna Teja G S
 * Dated : 2nd January 2015
 * Article : http://packetcode.com/article/jquery-image-slider-tutorial
-->

   <!-- 
 * Jquery Image Slider Tutorial 
 * File : index.html
 * Author : Krishna Teja G S
 * Dated : 2nd January 2015
 * Article : http://packetcode.com/article/jquery-image-slider-tutorial
-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Jquery Slider Demo</title>
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"  type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="slides">
 <div id="d1"> 
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb+@checkBoxesCounter" checked>
<br>            <label id="lb+@checkBoxesCounter" dicLabel="@x.Item1.ToString()">1lab1</label> <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb+@checkBoxesCounter" checked>
<br>            <label id="lb+@checkBoxesCounter" dicLabel="@x.Item1.ToString()">1lab2</label> <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb+@checkBoxesCounter">
        <br>    <label id="lb+@checkBoxesCounter" dicLabel="@x.Item1.ToString()">1lab3</label> <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb+@checkBoxesCounter" checked>
<br>            <label id="lb+@checkBoxesCounter" dicLabel="@x.Item1.ToString()">1lab4</label> <br>
 </div>
 <div id="d2">
   <input type="checkbox" id="cb+@checkBoxesCounter" >
       <br>     <label id="lb+@checkBoxesCounter" dicLabel="@x.Item1.ToString()">2lab1</label> <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb+@checkBoxesCounter" checked>
<br>            <label id="lb+@checkBoxesCounter" dicLabel="@x.Item1.ToString()">2lab2</label> <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb+@checkBoxesCounter">
        <br>    <label id="lb+@checkBoxesCounter" dicLabel="@x.Item1.ToString()">2lab3</label> <br>   
  </div>
 <div id="d3"> </div>
 <div id="d4"> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the fiddle we can see that the divs and their content (checkbox inputs and labels) are actually slided but the label are overlaid and the checkboxes are not clickable.

Comment: It's because you have given .top a z-index of -1 taking it behind the document - try something like 1: https://jsfiddle.net/x5otevf0/2/.  Ps I would hate a form where I had 3 seconds to select the options before the slide changed

Comment: You are using jquery image slider. I think you need to tweak your code a bit OR you can simply use a content slider like owl slider for better performance and compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I've used owl carousel to implement this:

```js
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  loop: true,
  nav: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>


<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox">label 1
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox">label 2
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox">label 3</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox">label 1
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox">label 2</div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox">label 1
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox">label 2
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox">label 3</div>
</div>
```